# Query does not include the specified expression

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've been stuck with a problem in MS Access. I am trying to add a collumn but I got a error.
"Your query does not include the specified expression 'BorgA' as part of an aggregate function."

I am using this Query:

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(A.TotaalPrijs) As TotaalPrijs,
    A.AutoNR,
    A.AutoKlasse,
    MAX(A.Factuur.Dagen) as Dagen,
    A.Prijzen.dag125KM as PrijsPerDag,
    A.Prijzen.ExtraKM As PrijsPerExtraKM,
    A.Factuur.FactuurNR,
    A.Factuur.KlantNR,
    A.Factuur.Begindatum,
    A.Factuur.Einddatum,
    A.Factuur.Borg,
    Gegevens.voorletters,
    Gegevens.tussenvoegsel,
    Gegevens.achternaam,
    Gegevens.straatnaam,
    Gegevens.huisNR,
    Gegevens.Postcode,
    Gegevens.rekeningNR,
    Gegevens.Plaats,
    A.KMteVEEL,
    B.BorgA
    FROM

    (SELECT Factuur.Dagen, Factuur.AutoNR AS carNR, autos.AutoNR, autos.Klasse AS AutoKlasse, Prijzen.Klasse, Prijzen.dag125KM, Prijzen.ExtraKM, (prijzen.dag125KM*Factuur.Dagen) AS MinPrijs, Factuur.FactuurNR, Factuur.KlantNR, Factuur.Begindatum, Factuur.Einddatum, Factuur.Borg, (KMteVEEL*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen]) AS TotaalPrijs, Gegevens.voorletters, Gegevens.tussenvoegsel, Gegevens.achternaam, Gegevens.straatnaam, Gegevens.huisNR, Gegevens.Postcode, Gegevens.rekeningNR, Gegevens.Plaats, IIf([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125) < 0, 0, [Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))  AS KMteVEEL
     FROM autos, Factuur, Prijzen, Gegevens
        WHERE (((Factuur.AutoNR)=Autos.AutoNR) And ((autos.Klasse)=Prijzen.Klasse) And ((Factuur.KlantNR)=Gegevens.KlantNR))

    ) AS A,
(SELECT  Prijzen.Borg as BorgA
FROM ((Prijzen 
     INNER JOIN Autos ON Autos.Klasse = Prijzen.Klasse)
     INNER JOIN Factuur ON Factuur.AutoNR = Autos.AutoNR)) AS B


    GROUP BY 
        A.AutoNR, A.AutoKlasse, A.Prijzen.dag125KM, A.Prijzen.ExtraKM, A.Factuur.FactuurNR, A.Factuur.KlantNR, A.Factuur.Begindatum, A.Factuur.Einddatum, A.Factuur.Borg, Gegevens.voorletters, Gegevens.tussenvoegsel, Gegevens.achternaam, Gegevens.straatnaam, Gegevens.huisNR, Gegevens.Postcode, Gegevens.rekeningNR, Gegevens.Plaats, A.KMteVEEL;
```

The code worked perfect before I added the `B.BorgA`and the

```
(SELECT  Prijzen.Borg as BorgA
FROM ((Prijzen 
     INNER JOIN Autos ON Autos.Klasse = Prijzen.Klasse)
     INNER JOIN Factuur ON Factuur.AutoNR = Autos.AutoNR)) AS B
```

Part.
Is there any way how to get it working?
I've tried adding B.BorgA in the GROUP BY but that didnt gave me the correct result.
Any other way how to get it working?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you running another `SELECT` from a table that's already in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Since you had no criteria to limit the join between your `A` subquery and `B` subquery you were getting a Cartesian product. Your subquery already joins to `Prijzen` so just add that into the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lists. Also other cleanup:

```
  SELECT 
        SUM(TotaalPrijs) As TotaalPrijs,
        AutoNR,
        AutoKlasse,
        MAX(Dagen) as Dagen,
        dag125KM as PrijsPerDag,
        ExtraKM As PrijsPerExtraKM,
        FactuurNR,
        KlantNR,
        Begindatum,
        Einddatum,
        Borg,
        voorletters,
        tussenvoegsel,
        achternaam,
        straatnaam,
        huisNR,
        Postcode,
        rekeningNR,
        Plaats,
        KMteVEEL,
        BorgA
        FROM     (SELECT p.Borg as BorgA,f.Dagen, f.AutoNR AS carNR, a.AutoNR, a.Klasse AS AutoKlasse, p.Klasse, p.dag125KM, p.ExtraKM, (p.dag125KM*f.Dagen) AS MinPrijs, f.FactuurNR, f.KlantNR, f.Begindatum, f.Einddatum, f.Borg, (KMteVEEL*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen]) AS TotaalPrijs, g.voorletters, g.tussenvoegsel, g.achternaam, g.straatnaam, g.huisNR, g.Postcode, g.rekeningNR, g.Plaats, IIf([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125) < 0, 0, [Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))  AS KMteVEEL
                  FROM autos a
                  INNER JOIN Factuur f  ON a.AutoNR = f.AutoNR
                  INNER JOIN Prijzen p  ON a.Klasse = p.Klasse
                  INNER JOIN Gegevens g ON f.KlantNR = g.KlantNR    

       ) AS sub
GROUP BY AutoNR,
        AutoKlasse,
        dag125KM, 
        ExtraKM,
        FactuurNR,
        KlantNR,
        Begindatum,
        Einddatum,
        Borg,
        voorletters,
        tussenvoegsel,
        achternaam,
        straatnaam,
        huisNR,
        Postcode,
        rekeningNR,
        Plaats,
        KMteVEEL,
        BorgA
```

I also eliminated your outdated `JOIN` syntax and added aliases.  The subquery isn't even necessary, but you'd have to change aliases appropriately if you eliminated it.

Comment: @Jesse What's the error? Oh perhaps because of the subquery name, updated.

Comment: @Jesse - this is not the right syntax to join more than one table

Comment: @GoatCO Still got the Syntax Error in FROM clause error.

Comment: @GoatCO I've added a comment to NoDisplayName's reaction. You might want to take a look at it since it might contain some usefull information.

Comment: @Jesse Not sure what syntax issue could exist, it gives no detail?  Unless your calculated field at the end is incorrect, there's really not much going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You have selected a non aggregate field  `B.BorgA` in select list but you missed to add it in `B.BorgA` in `group by`

```
Select ...
       ....
GROUP  BY A.AutoNR,
          A.AutoKlasse,
          A.Prijzen.dag125KM,
          A.Prijzen.ExtraKM,
          A.Factuur.FactuurNR,
          A.Factuur.KlantNR,
          A.Factuur.Begindatum,
          A.Factuur.Einddatum,
          A.Factuur.Borg,
          Gegevens.voorletters,
          Gegevens.tussenvoegsel,
          Gegevens.achternaam,
          Gegevens.straatnaam,
          Gegevens.huisNR,
          Gegevens.Postcode,
          Gegevens.rekeningNR,
          Gegevens.Plaats,
          A.KMteVEEL,
          B.BorgA;  -- Missed
```

Comment: If I add it in the GROUP BY the outcome isnt correct.

Comment: Here you can see it just gives all the possible 'borg' values.
http://gyazo.com/84df3b774b669cf043a37bf6fbb2354e
But when I just run the Subquery (the B one) seperate I get this:
http://gyazo.com/8dd415d26cef96e3d8e68b8f49d5c04d
As you can see on the last picture. That is the result I want to add in the 'main' query.