# syntax error missing operator

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've made a old question but I wasnt able to get it working with the answers:
[Old link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878610/query-does-not-include-the-specified-expression/27878859/)

Someone gave me this answer :

```
SELECT 
        SUM(TotaalPrijs) As TotaalPrijs,
        AutoNR,
        AutoKlasse,
        MAX(Dagen) as Dagen,
        dag125KM as PrijsPerDag,
        ExtraKM As PrijsPerExtraKM,
        FactuurNR,
        KlantNR,
        Begindatum,
        Einddatum,
        Borg,
        voorletters,
        tussenvoegsel,
        achternaam,
        straatnaam,
        huisNR,
        Postcode,
        rekeningNR,
        Plaats,
        KMteVEEL,
        BorgA
        FROM     (SELECT p.Borg as BorgA,f.Dagen, f.AutoNR AS carNR, a.AutoNR, a.Klasse AS AutoKlasse, p.Klasse, p.dag125KM, p.ExtraKM, (p.dag125KM*f.Dagen) AS MinPrijs, f.FactuurNR, f.KlantNR, f.Begindatum, f.Einddatum, f.Borg, (KMteVEEL*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen]) AS TotaalPrijs, g.voorletters, g.tussenvoegsel, g.achternaam, g.straatnaam, g.huisNR, g.Postcode, g.rekeningNR, g.Plaats, IIf([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125) < 0, 0, [Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))  AS KMteVEEL
                  FROM autos a
                  INNER JOIN Factuur f  ON a.AutoNR = f.AutoNR
                  INNER JOIN Prijzen p  ON a.Klasse = p.Klasse
                  INNER JOIN Gegevens g ON f.KlantNR = g.KlantNR    

       ) AS sub
GROUP BY AutoNR,
        AutoKlasse,
        dag125KM, 
        ExtraKM,
        FactuurNR,
        KlantNR,
        Begindatum,
        Einddatum,
        Borg,
        voorletters,
        tussenvoegsel,
        achternaam,
        straatnaam,
        huisNR,
        Postcode,
        rekeningNR,
        Plaats,
        KMteVEEL,
        BorgA
```

But I am getting a syntax error missing operator.
Any way to get this working?
You might want to check the old question out to understand the case better.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: @Jens Im getting Syntax Error Missing operator. Screenshot: http://gyazo.com/efb7149c3e624d0c2eb5ada56df9a6d9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access requires parentheses around `join` operators as `as` for table aliases.  Replace the `from` with:

```
FROM (SELECT p.Borg as BorgA, f.Dagen, f.AutoNR AS carNR, a.AutoNR, a.Klasse AS AutoKlasse, p.Klasse, 
             p.dag125KM, p.ExtraKM, (p.dag125KM*f.Dagen) AS MinPrijs, f.FactuurNR, f.KlantNR, 
             f.Begindatum, f.Einddatum, f.Borg,
             (KMteVEEL*[Prijzen]![ExtraKM])+([Prijzen]![dag125KM]*[Factuur]![Dagen]) AS TotaalPrijs,
             g.voorletters, g.tussenvoegsel, g.achternaam, g.straatnaam, g.huisNR, g.Postcode, 
             g.rekeningNR, g.Plaats,
             IIf([Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125) < 0, 0, [Factuur]![EindKMStand]-[Factuur]![BeginKMStand]-([Factuur]![Dagen]*125))  AS KMteVEEL
      FROM ((autos as a INNER JOIN
             Factuur as f
             ON a.AutoNR = f.AutoNR
            ) INNER JOIN
            Prijzen as p
            ON a.Klasse = p.Klasse
           ) INNER JOIN
           Gegevens as g
           ON f.KlantNR = g.KlantNR  
    ) sub
```

Of course, there might also be a problem with the arithmetic logic in the subquery.  Focus on getting the subquery to work first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now I am getting this error: http://gyazo.com/a8ef67d4e8ee886bbd6665963ed46f97

Comment: @Jesse . . . Try using a different name for the alias in the outer `select`.